# Image texture is not applied on the hairs when I reopen Blender (2.8)

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I'm trying to texturize the hairs of the 3D character using the **projection painting** tecnique. At the beginning the hairs are separated objects from the body. Then I spread the texture taken from a picture over their surface and finally I attach them to the rest of the body and I save the file.

But,when I reopen Blender (2.8),the base color is applied,but not the image that I want. I tried to join the objects in two ways. **Before I have selected the hairs and then the body** and I have joined them,but it didn't work. Then I tried to select **before the body and then the hairs** and I have joined them,but also in this case the image texture is not applied when I reopen the file. What's the solution here ? You can see what I did going [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XVC9snf_hoa3zCbuzLZVUmSgGuuaE1F9).

[image: hairs painted with the projection painting]
[image: hairs when I reopen blender]

Comment: Did you save the painting texture as an image to disk from the Image Editor?

Comment: something like this ? https://drive.google.com/open?id=1u5FODroNTUNcQaLgGyfzUEFfEUsEhR1x --> after this,what should I do ?

Comment: problem is that the hairs are attached to the body in one only object,so what should I do in this situation ?

Comment: The problem is that you are joining the mesh together but not fixing the UV mapping - you can see in your example frame that your uv islands are all overlapping. If you combine the meshes into one object or not, the image texture painted has to be saved and has to be referenced in the node tree.

Comment: can u show me how to reference the texture of the hair on the node tree ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make sure your UV map is clean enough to paint, then you can paint and then save the image to disk so it will keep the changed pixels. Using the image texture through an image texture node, you can specify the uv map to use so that it stays put in case you have multiple uv maps for other materials in your object.
[image]
[image]
[image]